# These two questions might be possible candidates for merging (after one is closed)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, merged-questions

Original: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Dup: [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

The dup has more upvotes but they both have the same accepted answer.